# Metrics don't show up on the /prometheus endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, prometheus, micrometer

I have two services, `ping` and `pong` where `ping` sends requests to `pong`. This metric shows up on the `/metrics` endpoint for the `ping` service:

`gauge.servo.hystrix.hystrixcommand.http://pong.pongclient#hello().90`

but it doesn't appear on the `/prometheus` endpoint. Other metrics appear on this endpoint, but not the servo metrics with information about Feign/Hystrix http requests.

How do I get those metrics to appear on the `/prometheus` endpoint?

I have the following dependencies on my `build.gradle`

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign'
compile 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-core:${micrometerVersion}"
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-spring-legacy:${micrometerVersion}"
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:${micrometerVersion}"
```

with the following versions

```
springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR4'
micrometerVersion = '1.0.0-rc.4'
```

The code can be found here https://github.com/fiunchinho/spring-resiliency

Comment: can you add a link to the sources?

Comment: https://github.com/fiunchinho/spring-resiliency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually add the plugin for Hystrix:

```
HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(new MicrometerMetricsPublisher(Metrics.globalRegistry));
```

You could add it in a `@PostConstruct` in a configuration.

I've created https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/237 to address the shortcoming in the future.

Answer (score 0):

checketts' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380868/60518) did not work for me and threw a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another strategy was already registered.` on startup, but adding the HystrixMetricsBinder bean, which does more or less the same internally, did the trick.

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

  @Bean
  HystrixMetricsBinder registerHystrixMetricsBinder() {
    return new HystrixMetricsBinder();
  }
}
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740957/60518

Answer (score -1):

You need to instrument and configure the spring boot services to monitor with prometheus as follows:

1. You need to include a dependency in the gradle.build file
2. You need to implement Metric endpoint
3. You need to add the standard exporters from Prometheus JVM

For more implementation details on how to do it see the examples [here](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/monitoring-spring-boot-applications-with-prometheus/) and also [here](https://reflectoring.io/monitoring-spring-boot-with-prometheus/)

Comment: Just to be clear: I see metrics on the /prometheus endpoint. It's just that I don't see the `servo` metrics with information about http requests being made with Feign/Hystrix.

Comment: This is all addressed with his usage of `micrometer-spring-legacy`. Micrometer.io will be the preferred way to monitor Spring applications going forward since it is baked into SpringBoot 2.

Comment: This answer doesn't specifically address the question about Hystrix metrics not showing up, and neither of the examples reference Hystrix either.