# Hystrix metrics in the actuator/metrics endpoint [spring-boot 2.0]

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, spring-boot-actuator

It is possible to get hystrix metrics information in a similar way as done in the spring-boot 1.5?

In 1.5 metric endpoint I have something like this:

```
"gauge.servo.hystrix.hystrixcommand.[service-name].[method].errorcount": 0,     
"gauge.servo.hystrix.hystrixcommand.[service-name].[method].requestcount": 0,
"gauge.servo.hystrix.hystrixcommand.[service-name].[method].latencytotal_mean": 0,
```

But now with actuator/metric endpoint that uses Micrometer, I can't find any reference to the terms "hystrix", "netflix", etc.

I alredy configured my application with `@EnableCircuitBreaker` and `hystrix:metrics:enabled: true`.

There is some way tho get this information without using the hystrix.stream endpoint as I was able before? Or this should be working and am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this [tutorial](https://tech.willhaben.at/monitoring-metrics-using-prometheus-a6d498dfcfba) you have to add the following bean to your application to register the Hystrix Metrics Binder:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

@Bean
HystrixMetricsBinder registerHystrixMetricsBinder() {
    return new HystrixMetricsBinder();
 }
}
```

As explainend in this [issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/683), hystrix metrics should now show up like this:

> hystrix.errors{event="short_circuited"}

Comment: @JoelC After some testing, the suggested answer works. Could you please remove your -1?

Comment: Good to hear; sorry I couldn't see how this answered the question. The -1 is not mine, I will remove my previous comment if I can.